# Make new users automatically follow a user

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php site with uses mysql as database, now my site is a social network like site where users follow each other, now if a user joins in he is following nobody so his stream remains empty so they leave the site quickly as well,i want users to be following my account account automatically when he joins in. Can you please tell me how to do it

here are the two tables

Table structure for table `sn_users`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sn_users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cover` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reg_id` text,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Table structure for table `sn_follows`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sn_follows` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Write a stored procedure. Write the queries for both following as well as insert both in a stored procedure and call that procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the query when the user get registerd.

```
<?
//Register query
$con = mysqli_connect("[HOST", "[USER]", "[PASS]", "[DB]");
$query1 = "INSERT INTO sn_users
          (username, email, password, name, picture, cover, job, address, date, reg_id, active)
          VALUES
          ('$username', '$email', '$password', '$name', '$picture', '$cover', '$job', '$address', 'date', 'reg_id', 'active')";
mysqli_query($con, $query);

//Auto follow query
 $query2 = "INSERT INTO sn_follows
            (`id`, `from`, `to`, `date`)
            VALUES
            ([ID], '[NEW REGISTERD ACCOUNT], '[YOUR ACCOUNT]', '[DATE]')";
 mysqli_query($con, $query2);
```

Hints:

- Make of the field `id` in your database an `auto_increment`
- Make sure you put a hashed password in the database

Comment: Made a new edit! make sure you understand! If you dont just ask it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do some modifications in your script.
1) get last inserted id of new registered user
2) insert that last id in sn_follows table with your id

this may elaborate flow
after your user register insert query get last id like below
example:

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO sn_users (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
$sqlfloow = "insert into sn_follows (from,to,date) values("your id",$last_id,date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))";
}
```